# Significato di "scuorno"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Ha perso il negozio, ha perso l’onore, ha perso Lena. Che altro gli resta? Che vonno ’sti polismen all’ausa mia? Chissà se i vicini li hanno visti salire. Ne parleranno per mesi. Che **scuorno**.

Sull'articolo "[Between Standard Italian and Creole](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1981.1143570)" di 
Hermann W. Haller ho trovato che "ausa" è un'italianizzazione di "house". Ma non capisco cosa sia "scuorno", vocabolo che non ho trovato su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste spiegarmelo? Immagino si tratti di un termine regionale, possibilmente correlato al napolitano.

Comment: Scorno: senso di umiliazione e di vergogna, spesso accompagnato da beffa o dal ridicolo.

Comment: @egreg: Non ricordavo l'esistenza della parola "scorno".

Comment: Infatti, alla [voce "scornoso" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_734.pdf) si spiega che questo aggettivo proviene dal napoletano *scurnuso*, derivato da *scuorno*, variante di *scorno* nel significato di 'vergogna, onta'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo [vocabolario di napoletano](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Schedario-napoletano-II.pdf) il termine ***scuorno*** viene così definito:

> **Scuorno**: *m.* pudore, vergogna.

In [questo blog](https://www.vesuviolive.it/cultura-napoletana/141140-miettete-scuorno-perche-si-dice-scuorno-e-da-dove-deriva/) vengono riportati, oltre alla definizione, anche etimologia e uso:

> **Il termine “scuorno” indica la “vergogna”, anche se per i partenopei
>   vi è una differenza sostanziale fra queste due parole**. Mentre la
>   vergogna è un sentimento personale che l’individuo può vivere anche in
>   maniera privata senza che i conoscenti ne sappiano nulla, lo “scuorno”
>   deve essere reso noto. 
>   ...
>   L’etimologia sarebbe greca. La parola “scuorno” trarrebbe origine dal
>   vocabolo ellenico αισχύνομαι che vuole dire appunto “vergognarsi”. Per
>   altri invece, come il linguista Raffaele Bracale, “scuorno”
>   deriverebbe dal latino “cornum”. La “s” aggiunta avrebbe un valore
>   privativo quindi il significato sarebbe “senza corno o corna” cioè
>   “scornato”. 
>   ... 
>   Così come l’animale senza la propria estremità perde il rispetto dei
>   suoi simili e viene per questo esiliato, così l’uomo che si deve
>   mettere “scuorno” è sottoposto alla gogna pubblica.

Infatti, [alla voce "scornoso" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_734.pdf) si spiega che questo aggettivo proviene dal napoletano *scurnuso*, derivato da *scuorno*, variante di *scorno* nel significato di 'vergogna, onta':

> **Scornóso**, agg. Dial. Vergognoso, timoroso, per lo più
>   per riserbo o timidezza. 
>         *A. Veraldi*, 7-14: I più scornosi, poi,
>   ch’erano quasi sempre i più giovani, per darsi aria e contegno si
>   presentavano sempre con un giornale arrotolato in mano come segno di
>   lettura e di istruzione. 
>         = Dal napol. *scurnuso*, deriv. da *scuorno*, var. di *scorno* nel signif. di ‘vergogna, onta’.

Comment: Usatissimo in tutto il sud, sopratutto in dialetto siciliano. La gestione pubblica della reputazione è un tema importantissimo in queste culture. Vedi per esempio romanzi di Andrea Camilleri.